# MpAndroidChart CandleStick Showing a range with dual seekbar?

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am using a dual seekbar to select the min and max range.

It works when taking the max range down, but when pulling the min range up it fails.

The range seekbar `OnRangeSekkbarChangedListener`:

```
RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer> skListener = new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {

                int max = bar.getSelectedMaxValue().intValue();
                int min = bar.getSelectedMinValue().intValue();

                mChart.resetTracking();

                //Hold of actual drawing lists
                List<CandleEntry> y = new ArrayList<CandleEntry>();
                List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = min; i < max ; i++){
                    //get candle entry from
                    CandleEntry current = yVals.get(i);
                    String currentDate = xVals.get(i);
                    y.add(current);
                    x.add(currentDate);
                }

                //Show less of the chart and invalidate
                CandleDataSet mSet = new CandleDataSet(y, "Price");
                mSet.setDecreasingColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mSet.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mSet.setIncreasingColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
                mSet.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mSet.setShadowColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

                mCandledata = new CandleData(x, mSet);
                //Don't show value text
                mCandledata.setDrawValues(false);

                mChart.setData(mCandledata);
                mChart.invalidate();
            }
        };

        rangeSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(skListener);
```

Results Sceenshots:

Initial Load:

[image: The Initial Chart]

Max Range pulled to near beginning:

[image: Max Range Pulled pulled near beginning]

Min Range pulled to near end:

[image: Min Range Seekbar pulled near end]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `xIndex` of the candle Entries. The first candle needs to have an `xIndex` of `0`

```
int xIndex = 0;
for (int i = min; i < max ; i++){
                    //get candle entry from
                    CandleEntry current = yVals.get(i);
                    String currentDate = xVals.get(i);
                    //set the xIndex value 
                    x.setXIndex(xIndex);
                    y.add(current);
                    x.add(currentDate);
                    xIndex++;
                }
```